# Find the values with criteria when condition matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, offset, datetimeoffset

I have data in format as below:

```
**"Month"**   **"Date & Time"**      **"kW"**
1              11/20/2014 11:30       234
1              11/21/2014 11:30       245
1              11/22/2014 0:00        345
2              11/23/2014 0:00        323
2              11/24/2014 0:00        234
2              11/25/2014 0:00        345
2              11/26/2014 0:00        434
3              11/27/2014 0:00        324
3              11/28/2014 0:00        436
3              11/29/2014 0:00        436
4              11/30/2014 0:00        235
4              12/1/2014 0:00         563
4              12/2/2014 0:00         342
4              12/3/2014 0:00         434
```

From the above data, I would like to get the values from 'Date & Time' and 'kW' when the condition matches.

The condition is--
When I write "1", then only the values in front of "1" will automatically appear. Same,
when I write "2", then only the values in front of "2" will appear.

I think it could be done by 'offset' with 'match/if' function in excel 2010, but it is not working properly. Please have a look onto it and try to resolve as early as possible.

The answer would be like that--
-When I write "1" in any particular cell for which the value is used to match the condition from 'Month' column then the values will come:

```
11/20/2014 11:30       234
11/21/2014 11:30       245
11/22/2014 0:00        345
```

-When I write "2", the values will come:

```
11/23/2014 0:00        323
11/24/2014 0:00        234
11/25/2014 0:00        345
11/26/2014 0:00        434
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a standard formula using `INDEX` and `SMALL` together with some helping functions.

[image: First Second Third with INDEX]

The formula in F2 is,

`=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$998)+($A$2:$A$999<>$E$2)*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))), "")`

Fill right to G2 then fill F2:G2 down enough rows to catch all possible matches.